# OPENID CONNECT (liferay gluu integration)

Tags: liferay

I am trying to integrate gluu server with liferay. I am following the link

1. [**How to deploy oxAuth Liferay plugin**](http://liferay.pbworks.com/w/page/83466418/How%20to%20deploy).
2. [**Glue server ubuntu installation guide**](http://www.gluu.org/docs/admin-guide/deployment/ubuntu/)

I have tested my gluu-server with **mod_auth_oidc** (ping identity) and it is working properly.So, I think there is no server side problem. But when I am following the above mentioned link,even the redirection is not happening and the logs are not helpful.

Q1. How to integrate using mod_auth_oidc + oxRay hook + gluuserver + liferay?

Q2. Where can I get oxAuthRP as a substitute of mod_auth_oidc?(as mod_auth_oidc is written in C)?

Q3. How to enable liferay as a Relying party?
Any other way to accomplish the task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to get more specific - as you currently ask the question it's not a good fit here, looks like you're looking for recommendations for tools.

Comment: @olaf kock Not only tools which will fit, but architecture also.